# How can I have my iOS app recognize which row/column a button is in?

Tags: ios, row

So I have 4 rows and 4 columns and each row and column contains 4 buttons

OOOO

OOOO

OOOO

OOOO

So when I click on the first O.  I want xcode to recognize that it is in row1 and column 1.

I have already declared everything as buttons, ints,etc.  But I need help defining rows/columns and placing these buttons in that row/column.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Is this a `UITableView`? A `UICollectionView`?

Comment: the simplest way would be to assign tags to buttons, e.g. `11` for button at r1c1 etc. (if you are going to have 9x9 max; for bigger tables you'd need a better algorithm of assigning numbers)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that these buttons are created using storyboard and that each one has a unique name. Provided all of this, you can create a 2-dimensional array adding each of these buttons to the appropriate spot in the array.

ex. `array[0][0] = button0`

This, while tedious, will solve this problem for your 16 button problem.